# OpenGL Shader vs CUDA

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, cuda, glsl

I was using [this](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/java/libraries/opengl/examples/Shaders/FXAA/data/fxaa.glsl?r=9668) FXAA Shader for anti-aliasing in my OpenGL program. Now I reimplemented this code in CUDA and tested it. The resulting images are the same, but the CUDA version is much slower. (Shader runs at 60 FPS with vsync, while CUDA drops down to ~40 FPS)

Here is the CUDA code:

```
__device__ uchar4 readChar(int x, int y){
    return surf2Dread<uchar4>( surfaceRead, (x)*sizeof(uchar4), (y),cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
}

__device__ uchar4 readFloatBilin2(float x, float y){
    int x1 = floor(x);
    int y1 = floor(y);

    uchar4 z11 = readChar(x1,y1);
    uchar4 z12 = readChar(x1,y1+1);
    uchar4 z21 = readChar(x1+1,y1);
    uchar4 z22 = readChar(x1+1,y1+1);

    float u_ratio = x - x1;
    float v_ratio = y - y1;
    float u_opposite = 1 - u_ratio;
    float v_opposite = 1 - v_ratio;
    uchar4 result = (z11   * u_opposite  + z21   * u_ratio) * v_opposite +
                    (z12 * u_opposite  + z22 * u_ratio) * v_ratio;


    return result;
}
__device__ float fluma(const uchar4 &c){
    return c.x*0.299 * (1.0/255) + c.y *0.587 * (1.0/255) + c.z*0.114 * (1.0/255);
}
__global__ void filter_fxaa_opt(TextureData data)
{

    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(x >= data.w || y >= data.h)
    {
        return;
    }

    uchar4 out_color;

    const float FXAA_SPAN_MAX = 8.0;
    const float FXAA_REDUCE_MUL = 1.0/8.0;
    const float FXAA_REDUCE_MIN = (1.0/128.0);



    float lumaNW = fluma(readChar(x-1,y-1));

    float lumaNE = fluma(readChar(x+1,y-1));

    float lumaSW = fluma(readChar(x-1,y+1));

     float lumaSE = fluma(readChar(x+1,y+1));

    float lumaM = fluma(readChar(x,y));

    float lumaMin = min(lumaM, min(min(lumaNW, lumaNE), min(lumaSW, lumaSE)));
    float lumaMax = max(lumaM, max(max(lumaNW, lumaNE), max(lumaSW, lumaSE)));

    float2 dir;
    dir.x = -((lumaNW + lumaNE) - (lumaSW + lumaSE));
    dir.y = ((lumaNW + lumaSW) - (lumaNE + lumaSE));

    float dirReduce = max((lumaNW + lumaNE + lumaSW + lumaSE) * (0.25 * FXAA_REDUCE_MUL), FXAA_REDUCE_MIN);

    float rcpDirMin = 1.0/(min(abs(dir.x), abs(dir.y)) + dirReduce);


//    float2 test = dir * rcpDirMin;
    dir = clamp(dir * rcpDirMin,-FXAA_SPAN_MAX,FXAA_SPAN_MAX);


    uchar4 rgbA = (
                readFloatBilin2(x+ dir.x * (1.0/3.0 - 0.5),y+ dir.y * (1.0/3.0 - 0.5))*0.5f+
                readFloatBilin2(x+ dir.x * (2.0/3.0 - 0.5),y+ dir.y * (2.0/3.0 - 0.5))*0.5f);
    uchar4 rgbB = rgbA * (1.0/2.0) +  (
                readFloatBilin2(x+ dir.x * (0.0/3.0 - 0.5),y+ dir.y * (0.0/3.0 - 0.5))*0.25f+
                readFloatBilin2(x+ dir.x * (3.0/3.0 - 0.5),y+ dir.y * (3.0/3.0 - 0.5))*0.25f);
    float lumaB = fluma(rgbB);


    if((lumaB < lumaMin) || (lumaB > lumaMax)){
        out_color=rgbA;
    } else {
        out_color=rgbB;
    }

    surf2Dwrite<uchar4>(out_color, surfaceWrite, x*sizeof(uchar4), y);
}
```

Setup:

```
//called for the 'src' and 'dst' texture once at the beginning
checked_cuda( cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&res, gl_buffer,gl_target, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore));

//called for the 'src' and 'dst' texture every frame
checked_cuda( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &res, 0));
checked_cuda( cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&array, res, 0,0));

//kernel call every frame
dim3 block_size(8, 8);
dim3 grid_size;
grid_size.x = (src->w) / (block_size.x) ;
grid_size.y = (src->h) / (block_size.y) ;
checked_cuda(cudaBindSurfaceToArray(surfaceRead, (cudaArray *)src->d_data));
checked_cuda(cudaBindSurfaceToArray(surfaceWrite, (cudaArray *)dst->d_data));
filter_fxaa_opt<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(*src);
```

System:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Opengl version: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.113
Renderer version: GeForce GTX 760M/PCIe/SSE2
CUDA 5.5
```

Question:
What does the OpenGL Shader do better and why is it so much faster?

Comment: How is some bare device code, with no information about how it is called, how the OpenGL interop has been set up, and how the benchmarking has been done supposed to allow us to explain frame rate differences to a completely unknown shader?

Comment: Added interop code. The shader used is a 1 to 1 copy from the link in my first sentence.

Comment: Are you implying in that code that you are mapping the OpenGL resource and binding the input and output surface on every frame? If so,why? Those calls are not free...

Comment: Currently yes, because i read somewhere that OpenGL could relocate data and then the mapping gets invalid. However i changed it so the mapping is done only once, but it didn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @dari: Your code contains many double-precision literal constants that force double-precision computation (by C/C++ type promotion rules) where single-precision computation was intended. Try appending the suffix 'f' to all floating-point constants (e.g. `0.299f`) and you should see speedup.

Comment: @dari: Also, try streamlining the bi-linear interpolation by expanding the terms and grouping them into multiply-add groups: `float a = (z21*u_ratio+(-z11*u_ratio+z11));
float b = (z22*u_ratio+(-z12*u_ratio+z12));
uchar4 result = (b*v_ratio+(-a*v_ratio+a));`. BTW, I am not clear on the assignment of a `float` value to a `uchar4` variable as the former is scalar but the latter is a short-vector type. Is that as intended?

Comment: @dari: Looking at the original shader code, I don't see any manual interpolation computation being done. The OpenGL code seems to be using the low-precision interpolation built-into the texturing hardware (which uses 1.8 fixed-point format). This will interpolate faster than using discrete interpolation using `float` computation. CUDA gives access to the built-in texture interpolation as well, see the CUDA C Programming Guide.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the hint, this indeed seemed to be the problem. After using build in interpolation and normalization the CUDA kernel and the OpenGL Shader do perform equally well (as much as i can tell). I didn't think, that manually interpolating could be so much slower, but it could be the case that there is specific hardware to read multiple pixels and interpolate the result, because it's a pretty common task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As njuffa pointed out the main problem was the manual interpolation and normalization. After using a CUDA `texture` instead of a CUDA `surface` the build in interpolation can be used by calling `tex2D(..)` instead of `surf2Dread(...)`.

The modified CUDA code is now almost indentically to the OpenGL shader and does indeed perform equally well.

```
__global__ void filter_fxaa2(TextureData data)
{

    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(x >= data.w || y >= data.h)
    {
        return;
    }

    uchar4 out_color;

    const float FXAA_SPAN_MAX = 8.0f;
    const float FXAA_REDUCE_MUL = 1.0f/8.0f;
    const float FXAA_REDUCE_MIN = (1.0f/128.0f);

    float u = x + 0.5f;
    float v = y + 0.5f;

    float4 rgbNW = tex2D( texRef, u-1.0f,v-1.0f);
    float4 rgbNE = tex2D( texRef, u+1.0f,v-1.0f);
    float4 rgbSW = tex2D( texRef, u-1.0f,v+1.0f);
    float4 rgbSE = tex2D( texRef, u+1.0f,v+1.0f);
    float4 rgbM = tex2D( texRef, u,v);

    const float4 luma = make_float4(0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f,0.0f);
    float lumaNW = dot(rgbNW, luma);
    float lumaNE = dot(rgbNE, luma);
    float lumaSW = dot(rgbSW, luma);
    float lumaSE = dot(rgbSE, luma);
    float lumaM = dot( rgbM, luma);

    float lumaMin = min(lumaM, min(min(lumaNW, lumaNE), min(lumaSW, lumaSE)));
    float lumaMax = max(lumaM, max(max(lumaNW, lumaNE), max(lumaSW, lumaSE)));

    float2 dir;
    dir.x = -((lumaNW + lumaNE) - (lumaSW + lumaSE));
    dir.y = ((lumaNW + lumaSW) - (lumaNE + lumaSE));

    float dirReduce = max((lumaNW + lumaNE + lumaSW + lumaSE) * (0.25f * FXAA_REDUCE_MUL), FXAA_REDUCE_MIN);

    float rcpDirMin = 1.0f/(min(abs(dir.x), abs(dir.y)) + dirReduce);


    float2 test = dir * rcpDirMin;
    dir = clamp(test,-FXAA_SPAN_MAX,FXAA_SPAN_MAX);

    float4 rgbA = (1.0f/2.0f) * (
                tex2D( texRef,u+ dir.x * (1.0f/3.0f - 0.5f),v+ dir.y * (1.0f/3.0f - 0.5f))+
                tex2D( texRef,u+ dir.x * (2.0f/3.0f - 0.5f),v+ dir.y * (2.0f/3.0f - 0.5f)));
    float4 rgbB = rgbA * (1.0f/2.0f) + (1.0f/4.0f) * (
                tex2D( texRef,u+ dir.x * (0.0f/3.0f - 0.5f),v+ dir.y * (0.0f/3.0f - 0.5f))+
                tex2D( texRef,u+ dir.x * (3.0f/3.0f - 0.5f),v+ dir.y * (3.0f/3.0f - 0.5f)));
    float lumaB = dot(rgbB, luma);


    if((lumaB < lumaMin) || (lumaB > lumaMax)){
        out_color=toChar(rgbA);
    } else {
        out_color=toChar(rgbB);
    }


    surf2Dwrite<uchar4>(out_color, surfaceWrite, x*sizeof(uchar4), y);
}
```

Update:

Performance meassured with `cudaEvents`:

- Old Version: ~12.8ms
- New Version: ~1.2ms

Conclusion:

Use CUDA surfaces only for writing and not for reading textures!